# /tmp/mysql.socket files is missing in ubuntu server 10.4

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

i have started mysql server but the /tmp/mysql.socket file is missing.

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.socket'

what to do?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your socket's probably elsewhere, most likely `/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock`. If there's a /etc/my.cnf or /etc/my.ini, the location will be specified there.